# How do i make a fluid float:left layout?

Tags: javascript, css, grid, css-float

For example, i'd like to have a grid of boxes all floating left. I have the design here: atbskate.com/trusktr.

The boxes on my site are all float:left. However, when i expand a box by adding content into it (ajax) it shifts the other boxes and leaves an ugly empty space. I'd like for the boxes to fill up this empty space.

The idea would be similar to http://www.robclarke.com/. when you click on a box, it expans, and all the other boxes are shifted and there is no empty space. How can I avoid this empty space?

The code on robclarke.com is very complex so i ahven't had time to disect it...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the jQuery [masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com) which provides for a lot of flexibility in handling content in boxes.

Comment: Lol, indeed this is what I discovered More than a year ago. hehe

Comment: Heh, I didn't check the question date... but, maybe this will help someone else anyway.